# HTTP Error 403: Forbidden on urllib when I'm trying to get profile pic of a new member with my discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.py, httpwebrequest, urllib, webrequest

I'm coding a discord.py discord BOT. Now I'm writing the "on_member_join", and I'm trying to get the new member profile pic to make a custom image of welcome. Here's the issue. When I start the program, and a member join the server, the request is correctly send, but I receive the `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` error.

My code:

```
import discord
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw,ImageFont
import urllib.request

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):

    url = f"{member.avatar_url}"

    name = "profile.png"

    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, name)
```

Remember that I need to download the image because I have to customize it with the "Pillow library"

Comment: Can you add the full traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`discord.Member.avatar_url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.avatar_url) (I am linking to the `User` equivalent as the docs redirect there anyway) returns an Asset that you can call [`await read()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Asset.read) on. This will give you a byte representation of the avatar that you can directly read into a Pillow `Image` like so:

```py
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

avatar_bytes = await member.avatar_url.read()
im = Image.open(BytesIO(avatar_bytes))
```

If you need to save the original avatar to disk, you can use [`save()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Asset.save) instead of `read()`